# How to initialise a shift register in VHDL?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, shift-register

I'm trying to make a vhdl implementation of  an 8-bit shift register that is initialized to  "11111111" each time a reset push button is pressed, before the shift register starts to receive  values from a random binary sequence generator.

How do I go about implementing this in vhdl ?

Comment: Let's see your code so that we can see where you're going wrong with what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether the reset is synchronous or asynchronous.

For an asynchronous reset, it would be something like this:

```
process (CLK, ARST)
begin
  if (ARST = '1') then
    --insert reset logic here
  elsif (rising_edge(CLK)) then
    --insert regular logic here
  end if;
end process;
```

With a synchronous reset:

```
process (CLK, RST)
begin
  if (rising_edge(CLK)) then
    if (RST = '1') then
      --insert reset logic here
    else
      --insert regular logic here
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```